# I need Adobe AIR For Android Encrypted Local Store or Application Storage data to persist even after uninstalling or updating the app.

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

According to Encrypted Local Store documentation, ELS should persist as long as the Android AIR App's application ID is kept the same even though the app version number is different. Unfortunately this is not the case based on my experience. I have set the stronglybound paramater to false as well.

Sample code here:

```
//saving
var baWrite:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
baWrite.writeObject(appData);
EncryptedLocalStore.setItem(APP_DATA_NAME, baWrite);

//loading
var baRead:ByteArray = EncryptedLocalStore.getItem(APP_DATA_NAME);
appData = baRead.readObject();
```

My theory is that Publisher ID needs to be set also but I am not really sure.

Comment: Is your problem that the data is lost when a user upgrades versions of the app? Are both versions of the app the same version of AIR? What is the version of AIR you are using?

Answer (score 0):

according to documents here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e31.html it says:

copy from adobe doc: Data in the ELS can be lost for a variety of reasons. For example, the user could uninstall the application and delete the encrypted file. Or, the publisher ID could be changed as a result of an update. Thus the ELS should be treated as a private cache, not a permanent data storage.